# Remove the dash "-" before and after the filename

Tags: vbscript

I have data that I am trying to remove a character from.

I have a file out there on my server which is A-549131-B.

I would like for my script to remove the A- and the -B and keep what's in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a regular expression, like this:

```
filename = "..."

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^.*-(.*)-.*(\..*)$"

Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(filename)
f.Name = re.Replace(f.Name, "$1$2")
```

Answer (score 1):

this depends on the language you use. in php, use explode and set the split string to be "-", that way, the digits would be the second element of the resulting array

Comment: The question is tagged VBScript.